# Книга по разработке игр

Tags: книги

Хочу почитать книгу , о разработке игр (желательно не привязанную к каким то языкам, или хотя бы на C# или javascript).
Видел много хороших отзывов о книге:
"Проектирование и архитектура компьютерных игр" (Game Architecture and Design ) Andrew Rollings, Dave Morris
но так ее и не нашел на русском( в электронном виде) .
Что посоветуете?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал выучить английский и читать на нём.

Comment: можно посоветовать учить английский или читать форумы

Comment: я его учу, но пока мой уровень не дотягивает до чтения учебников на английском

Comment: по книгам советов не будет, я так понимаю?

Comment: @cyber_ua google уже не в моде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь читайте книги не столько по разработке игр, сколько по компьютерной графике. Важно также иметь хороший математический базис - скорее всего, если действительно хотите заняться этим хоть сколько-то серьезно, придется часто иметь дело с со  всякого рода матаном (если вам ни о чем не говорят такие умные слова как "кватернион", "матрица", "преобразования координат", "сканлайн", то самое время заняться вплотную всем матаном)
Зайдите на gameDev.ru, там можно почерпнуть кое-чего полезного. Заодно гнома посмотрите))

Comment: >Важно также иметь хороший математический базис
это я знаю...

> "кватернион", "матрица", "преобразования координат", "сканлайн"
ну тут 50 на 50)
>Заодно гнома посмотрите))
O_o , гнома?)
"по компьютерной графике"
не посоветуете?

Comment: извините за такой вопрос, а в чем ваши математические познания заключаются?

Comment: в 2х курсах универа)

Comment: ах вот оно что) не хочу вас разочаровывать, но...впрочем, вам виднее.
Скажу лишь, что создать свой Crysis, но с блэкджеком и барышнями у вас не получится, но если отнесетесь к этому с должным усердием, то можете получить массу очень полезного опыта. 
 А по сабжу почитайте вот это например: 
http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/93117/

Comment: да я даже о 3д графике даже и не задумываюсь)
в данный момент интересно почитать об алгоритмах, как строить уровни ...
за ссылку спасибою

Answer (score 2):

Неистово плюсую Жака Арсака. А со всякими там архитектурами и дизайнами не советую заморачиваться. В играх гораздо важнее алгоритмы. Смешно бывает видеть, как какой-нибудь джавист с ООПом головного мозга накалякал жуткую мешанину классов только потому, что не знает про Zobrist hash. Или еще что-нибудь в этом роде. Почитайте на хабре поучительную статью про то, как два программиста хлеб пекли. Погуглите не менее поучительную историю с игрушкой Starship Troopers, создатели которой, может, и знали про архитектуру и дизайн, но не знали про автоматное программирование, использовавшееся даже в примитивном Пэкмане.

Еще советую почитать про Вадима Башурова AKA papabubadiop. Человек пишет без всяких затей и архитектурных заморочек, зато просто, надежно и много. Заработал уже миллион баксов.

Возможно, мой тон Вам покажется каким-то поучающим. Дело в том, что я сам через все это прошел. Я потерял кучу времени на книги по теории. Они нужны в первую очередь командам программистов, работающих над крупными проектами. Я не призываю говнокодить. Я призываю писать и учиться в процессе. По-другому не получится. В этом программирование похоже на медицину. Даже если ты гений с золотыми медалями и красными дипломами, никто тебя к сложным случаям не допустит. Надо сначала наработать огромный опыт, вырезая аппендициты.

Answer (score 0):

Жак Арсак "Программирование игр и головоломок"